# Purposefully throw 404 error when symfony2 url contains 'app.php' to mask the framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, apache2

How can I change the default symfony2 .htaccess to specifically throw a 404 error when app.dev is found in the URI? The default behavior is to hide app.php and carry onto the request (this taking you to the / route). I don't want app.php or app_dev.php to be browsable when queried directly because then people will know I'm using Symfony2.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe use a modified version of anubhavas answer and redirect requests coming to app / app_dev to a new route handled by symfony "/page-not-found" Then have that route throw a "Symfony 404"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this rule as your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+app\.dev [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Any sneaky way to transform that to a symfony2 404? :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. But it's still a smoking gun as it directs this to an apache 404 - not a symfony2 404 with my pretty page. Worst case scenario, I can duplicate the content for the 404 page and make it apache's default. But there must be a better workaround!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience in Symfony to suggest you something on that.